# How do I select blank records and concatenate them onto records with data without having trailer/leading spaces?

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

So I have a select

```
select
       PART_NO,
       FIPS_COUNTY_CODE as COUNTY_CODE, 
       LAST AS LNAME,
       FIRST AS FNAME,
       IsNull(ALTADDR, '') + ' ' + DELADDR as ADDRESS,
       CITY,
       STATE,
       ZIP,
       SEX,
       RACE,
       STATUS,
       convert(datetime, BIRTHDATE) as DOB,
       H_PHONE,
       VOTER_DIV,
       VOTER_REG,
       JUD_CODE,
       [LICENSE NO] AS D_LICENSE,
       SIN,
       DATE_SELECTED1,
       DATE_SELECTED2,
       DATE_SELECTED3,
       PART_NO - 100000000 AS REC_NUM,
       PERM_DISQUAL,
       SCAN_CODE,
       DIVISION AS DIVISION_CODE,
       OFFICIAL_USE,
       COURT_EMP,
       HISPANIC,
       NOTES,
       CITIZEN,
       DATE_UPD,
       DS as SOURCE,
       CELL_PHONE,
       W_PHONE,
       W_PH_LOCAL,
       EMAIL,
       PENDING_IND,
       PENDING_EXPIRES,
       LOGIN_LOCK,
       DATE_SELECTED4,
       QUALIFIED_DATE,
       POOL_CREATION_DATE
       into FINAL
 INTO FINAL
 FROM NCOASUPPRESS
```

And ALTADDR and DELADDR need to be combined, for example:

```
ALTADDR = APT B1
DELADDR = 1000 Goggins Ln
```

Expected Result = APT B1 1000 Goggins Ln

But sometimes ALTADDR is blank, so what happens is an extra space gets put in before the expected result. Also after...? But it doesn't do this for any other field. I tried LTRIM/RTRIM but they didn't seem to work. I essentially need this field trimmed for leader and trailing blank space, but the trim functions did not seem to work for me.

Comment: Can you show how you attempted to use `RTRIM` and `LTRIM`? There are some solid solutions below that will work.

Answer (score 0):

Handle the space inside the `COALESCE()`:

```
   COALESCE(ALTADDR + ' ', '') +  DELADDR as ADDRESS,
```

Comment: @rohanharrison . .  How does it not work?  There is no way it could *add* a space at the beginning.  You would get a space at the beginning if `ALTADDR` is empty (or consists of spaces) or if `DELADDR` starts with a space.

Comment: That is probably it, but still, LTRIM and RTRIM do not work for me either.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `CONCAT`

```
CONCAT(ALTADDR + ' ', DELADDR) as ADDRESS
```

this will handle `NULL` on both `ALTADDR` and `DELADDR`

**EDIT**

OTT approach: `CONCAT(LTRIM(RTRIM(ALTADDR)) + ' ', LTRIM(RTRIM(DELADDR))) as ADDRESS`

Comment: This will leave a space at the beginning if `ALTADDR = ' '`

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you used `L/RTRIM()`incorrectly....

```
declare @ALTADDR varchar(64) = ' '
declare @DELADDR varchar(64) = '1000 Goggins Ln'

SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM(CONCAT(RTRIM(@ALTADDR) + ' ',LTRIM(@DELADDR)))) as ADDRESS
```

This ensures you don't have leading or trailing spaces regardless if the field is `' '` or `NULL`

Answer (score 0):

Since you have already tried `ltrim()` and `rtrim()`, you probably have extra white space characters in your data that aren't the actual space character.

To replace tabs, new lines, and carriage returns... Try:

```
address = replace(replace(replace(isnull(altaddr + ' ', '') +  deladdr
            ,char(10),'') /* new line */
            ,char(13),'') /* carriage return */
            ,char(9),'')  /* tab */
```

If you still see spaces, wrap the above in `ltrim(rtrim(replace...))`.

this version would help chop whitespace off the beginning, but not the end:

```
    address = substring((isnull(altaddr + ' ', '') +  deladdr)
          , patindex('%[a-z0-9]%',(isnull(altaddr + ' ', '') + deladdr))
          , 8000)
```

Answer (score 0):

super trim

```
SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM(CONCAT(' ' + LTRIM(RTRIM(ALTADDR)), ' ' + LTRIM(RTRIM(DELADDR)))))
```